# How to accurately display string in JComboBox?

Tags: java, string, swing, jcombobox, illegal-characters

I have an array of strings that represent options in a drop-down menu.

```
        String[] s_reflection_map = {
                "x=W–1–x mod W                               ",
                "x/W even x=x mod W; odd x=W–1–x mod W, no PI",
                "same, but with Pixel Interpolation          ",
                "x=x mod W/2, y=y mod H/2                    ",
                "x>W–1,x=x mod W else x=W–1–x mod W          ",
                "x<W,x=x mod W//2 else x=W–1–x mod W         ",
                "x/W even,x=x mod W/2;odd x=W–1–x mod W/2    ",
                "x/W even,x=x mod W/2;odd x=(W–1)/2–x mod W/2",
                "simple                                      "
        };

        JComboBox<String> jcb_reflection_map = new JComboBox<>(s_reflection_map);
```

Minus sign, the character "-" cannot be displayed correctly.

[image: JComboBox shown in configuration JFrame window]

Can anyone remind me of why minus is illegal character?

Comment: There seems to be some encoding around the characters, try putting them into a plain text editor and saving them as plain text and then copy them back in and see if they make a difference...

Answer (score 3):

The subtraction symbols are encoded as literal Unicode [`EN DASH' (U+2013)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) characters, the preferred glyph in a mathematical context. In Java source, substitute the corresponding escape, for example,

```
"x=W\u20131\u2013x mod W                               ",
```

Comment: See also [`java.util.Properties#load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-).

Answer (score 0):

This is the format that works well.

```
"x = W \u2013 x mod W"
```